# I want to download sql server on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, system-installation

i run `"sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server"`
I get:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mssql-server : Depends: libldap-2.4-2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please, [edit] your question to add your Ubuntu version/release and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and add the full `apt install ... ` command that you used.

Comment: In case the version is 22.04: mssql does not support ubuntu 22.04 and we can not fix that. Microsoft needs to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)